# React constructor

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6

What difference does it make to pass props to the constructor of a `React.Component`

```
constructor(props) {
     super(props); 
}
```

vs

```
constructor() {
     super();
 }
```

I don't see any noticeable difference between the two. This question is different because I do not have props being passed into the constructor and there is no difference in the component.